# How to nest and chain my class functions with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I make such code parts work?
Trying to complete task with custom HTML builder - it needs to support chaining and nesting.
Understand that I need to return *this*, but how then to output string with HTML?

```
// nesting
    const template = Templater().div(
     Templater().p('Hello'),
     Templater().p('World')
    )
    console.log(template.toString())
// chaining 
console.log(Templater().br('error').toString())
```

example of Class that I try to create:

```
    class Templater {
    constructor() {}
    div(tags) {
        return `<div>${tags}</div>`
    }
    span(tags) {
        return `<span>${tags}</span>`
    } 
    br(argument) {
        if(argument) {
            return new Error('Nested content is not allowed');
        } else {
            return '<br>'
        }
    } 
    p(tags) {
        return `<p>${tags}</p>`
    } 
}
```

Have no idea what I need to do.

Comment: What is the expected output of the chaining?

Comment: You can't call a `class` you need to instantiate a new object with `new`

Comment: No, you should not `return this`. You should return a `new Template(…)`. Think of the values you want the new instance to hold, and pass these into the constructor and store them as properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you primarily need a custom `toString` method that returns the state of the tags called so far.

You'll also need to change the class to a function, because classes cannot be used without `new`.

```js
const templater = () => {
  let markup = '';
  const transform = tags => tags.join('');
  return {
    div(...tags) {
      markup += `<div>${transform(tags)}</div>`
      return this;
    },
    span(...tags) {
      markup += `<span>${transform(tags)}</span>`
      return this;
    },
    br(argument) {
      if (argument) {
        throw new Error('Nested content is not allowed');
      } else {
        markup += '<br>'
        return this;
      }
    },
    p(...tags) {
      markup += `<p>${transform(tags)}</p>`
      return this;
    },
    toString() {
      return markup;
    },
  };
};

// nesting
const template = templater().div(
  templater().p('Hello'),
  templater().p('World')
)
console.log(template.toString())
console.log(templater().br('error').toString())
```

Comment: Thank you - that's great option. But what if I use module that allows me not to use new and I need to create this functionality with Class only? Is it possible to create such variable as markup and add html to it?

Comment: Changing the logic to a `class` is quite simple, but the syntax would be invalid since you're calling it without `new`.

Comment: I'd even recommend to do `templater = (markup = '') => {` and then `return templater(markup + '…');` instead of mutating the `markup` variable.

Comment: But as I understand class doesn't allows me to create variable inside by let, const. But If I use public and static fields - it doesn't allows me change them. Can you desribe where to save strings content in such class?

Comment: Constructor - just got it. Thank you very much! This was ultra helpful.